# Woocommerce custom field variation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I used this tutorial to build my woocommerce custome field :

[Woocommerce custom field variation](http://www.remicorson.com/mastering-woocommerce-products-custom-fields/#comments)

I just picked up the number field :

[My code on pastbin](http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=HYzz9mz7)

When using this code the field is shown on the admin screen, inside product variation section, and when i fill it with number it works but when i update it twice or more the field not updated, it always keep old value.

Anyone can help please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code:

```
    add_action('woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_variable_fields', 10, 2);

    function save_variable_fields($variation_id, $i)
    {
        $variable_number_field        = $_POST['_number_field'];
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_number_field', wc_clean( $variable_number_field[ $i ] ) );

    }
```

My current woocommerce is 2.3.8